# react-select styling from classes

Tags: css, reactjs, dropdown, react-select

I have given className as `react-select-container` and `classNamePrefix` as `react-select`. The styles described in the CSS is getting overwritten by the inbuilt style of the `react-select`. Image shows `react-select__control` styles is getting overwritten by the styles of some default class `css-yk16xz-control` of the react select. i want it to work the other way around and `react-select__control` styles stay on top and its styles get applied. any suggestions.

```
render() {
  const titleOptions  = [{value: 'Dr.', label: 'Dr.'}, {value:'Eng.', label:'Eng.'}, {value:'Officer', label:'Officer'}];
  return (
    <Select options={titleOptions} autoFocus className="react-select-container" classNamePrefix="react-select" />
  )
}
```

[Check Dom structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9BWq.png)

```
.react-select__control {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you provided the code you are using.

Comment: You can edit your question and provide the code within code blocks using markdown formatting. The editor has popup help to assist you with formatting.

Comment: any suggestions?